# Sencha Touch Documentation Live Preview

Tags: google-chrome, sencha-touch-2

I've just installed Aptana Studio3 with senchatouch 2. 
I would like to use the documentation which is installed with the Sencha sdk, everything seems displayed fine but I have no way to get Live Preview in the example. When I go on line on the sencha site it's ok.
I'm under Windows 7 64 bits with last version of Chrome.
Would somebody got similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly run the application. You need to host it on your own local web server, I use Apache Tomcat. Copy the entire downloaded Sencha Touch SDK. Start server and hit the url.

http://{your ip}:{port}/AppServerName/sencha-touch-2.0.1.1/examples/kiva/index.html

This should work.